# I have to code a FTP client. No idea where to start. C++

Tags: c++, ftp, client, ftp-client

I got that nice assignment in school - create a simple ftp client. Something graphically like midnight commander is enough, so I don't need any graphical libraries. But... What would you suggest to use for the networking part? Never done this before :( Please be as specific as possible, means a lot to me.

Thanks guys, have a nice day ;)

Comment: _"Please be as specific as possible, means a lot to me."_ Specific about what? There's nothing essentially _specific_ asked in your question, so what do you expect actually?

Comment: Start with a writing a TCP/IP client and read the FTP RFC https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt  Important: get your own FTP server up and running (there are plenty of free ones) to develop againt; DO NOT try and develop against an FTP server on the internet without obtaining permission first

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much choice for the "networking part". Ye olde sockets will work just as well for `FTP` as for any other networking application.